# How to reference a PPP adapter in a netsh command?

Tags: windows, dns, netsh

When using the windows command `ipconfig /all`, the result will show a PPP adapter followed by a long name closed with braces. It looks like the below image:

[image]

When I try to set the DNS of my PPP adapter, I encounter this problem:

```
netsh interface ip set dns "PPP adapter {1C43A7B0-1173-40E2-96D6-1DA6457786B0}" static 208.67.222.222
Invalid interface PPP adapter {1C43A7B0-1173-40E2-96D6-1DA6457786B0} specified.
```

I have also used the pure string "{1C43A7B0-1173-40E2-96D6-1DA6457786B0}", but with the same result.

How can I reference this PPP adapter, so that I can change its configured DNS and other settings?

What does this long string mean?

I do not have this PPP adapter connection on my "show all connections" panel, because I have a VPN app - when running it, this PPP adapter will be automatically created for me.

Comment: What are you using for your connection software? You may, or may not, be able to set it.

Comment: For future reference, the number string you have there - {1C43A7B0-1173-40E2-96D6-1DA6457786B0} - is called a Globally Unique Identifier (GUID) or Universally Unique Identifier (UUID).  (The difference between the two is essentially semantic.)

Answer (score 2):

I just tried your command with a PPP adapter I have, and I think your syntax is wrong. Try this:

> netsh interface ip set dns {1C43A7B0-1173-40E2-96D6-1DA6457786B0} static 208.67.222.222

In other words, the reason it failed is that "PPP adapter" is not part of the name, and the GUID is just a name Windows gave that adapter in the registry.

Comment: If this works for you, please come back and mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: Hi, thanks for all the replies and help, and I just tried the Kcotreau's method, but I'm sorry, it does not work either.

Comment: 2011-06-17 added:
In fact, I use a L2TP VPN Client APP in my school, This is a dialing program. I need to supply a user name and password, after its dialing up, I can access to the world wide internet. 

    Here is the result
    netsh interface ip set dns {1C43A7B0-1173-40E2-96D6-1DA6457786B0} static 208.67.222.222
    Invalid interface {1C43A7B0-1173-40E2-96D6-1DA6457786B0} specified.

Comment: @ollydbg23 One more try: Try it without the {}. By the way, when I did it, I had an actual adapter name, not a GUID.

Comment: Thank you Kontreau for the help, current I'm at home, I will test and give the reply when I return to my office at school.

Comment: Hi, KCotreau, I just test it with out the {}, the result is the same, see below:netsh interface ip set dns 1C43A7B0-1173-40E2-96D6-1DA6457786B0 static 208.67.222.222

Invalid interface 1C43A7B0-1173-40E2-96D6-1DA6457786B0 specified.